# SOLR Down boosting on field Value

Tags: solr

I have got this query in solr. The problem is, i am getting search results that contains a category of items named "PRD DELETED".
Now all the items that have "PRD DELETED", i want to display those at the end.
For Ex if 100 records are there and one page contains 25 records, then on the last page "PRD DELETED" records should display.

Pls note that "PRD DELETED" is a value and not any category. I think down boosting is needed here, but i am unable to find the exact solution.

Any suggestion here would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is usually to do the opposite: boost all documents that isn't deleted, instead of trying to negatively boost those that is. Boosts are either multiplicative or additive, and while multiplicative boosts can reduce the score value, the additive can't. `bq` and `qf` are additive, while `boost` is multiplicative.

The [Relevancy FAQ has an example](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F) for this case:

> When using (e)dismax, people sometimes expect that specifying a pure negative query with a large boost in the "bq" param will work (since Solr automatically makes top level purely negative positive queries by adding an implicit "*:*" -- but this doesn't work with "bq", because of how queries specified via "bq" are added directly to the main query. You need to be explicit...
>
> ```
> ?defType=dismax 
> &q=foo bar 
> &bq=(*:* -xxx)^999
> ```

Implementing it as a multiplicative boost would probably involve using `if` and then returning either 1 or a lower value depending on whether the field has the given value.